# Como fazer controle de concorrência no Hibernate para INSERT no banco de dados

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, hibernate, aplicação-web, concorrência

Estou com um problema de controle de concorrência na inserção de dados em minha aplicação Web.

Contexto: tenho 3 tabelas (ex: X, Y e Z) que registram internações de pacientes (já cadastrados). Um paciente não pode ter mais do que uma internação ATIVA simultaneamente.

Atualmente, minha aplicação apenas verifica se já existe alguma internação ativa para aquele paciente antes de iniciar a transação que faz os INSERTs nas tabelas X, Y e Z.

Contudo essa verificação não funciona quando dois ou mais usuários tentam internar dois pacientes ao mesmo tempo.

Atualmente o tratamento é feito assim:

```
1 - verifica se o paciente está internado (SELECT na tabela X);
Se não:
  inicia transação A;
    2 - INSERT na tabela X;
    3 - INSERT na tabela Y;
    4 - INSERT na tabela Z;
  finaliza transação A;
```

Como disse anteriormente, a verificação em 1 ocorre para evitar que pacientes sejam internados mais de uma vez ao mesmo tempo. Contudo, se dois (ou mais) usuários tentarem internar o mesmo paciente ao mesmo tempo, a verificação de 1 não funciona.

O que eu pensei de solução:

Pensei em algo que envolva bloquear o SELECT em 1, para que ele somente seja executado quando a transação A for finalizada. Nesse caso, ao ser executado, o SELECT iria identificar que o paciente já está cadastrado.

Gostaria de tratar esse problema utilizando LOCK no banco de dados. Utilizo PostgreSQL e, pelo que estudei, precisaria usar o ACCESS EXCLUSIVE (único que bloqueia SELECT)

**Como fazer isso utilizando o Hibernate?**

*Obs: já analisei e não é possível tratar com constraints no banco de dados*

Comment: Por que não é possível tratar com constraint?

Comment: O passo _"verifica se o paciente está internado"_ deveria fazer parte da transação. Se houver impacto em transacionar toda vez, você pode fazer duas vezes o passo, uma vez fora e outra dentro da transação, como ocorre em certas implementações de checagem de `null` ao se instanciar um _Singleton_.

Answer (score 1):

Você já pensou em utilizar a estratégia lock otimista ? É um recurso do hibernate que cria uma coluna no banco de dados representando a versão daquele registro.

Caso você estiver utilizando um sistema Web (feito em Spring por exemplo) você pode mandar esta versão como um campo hidden no formulário. Aí quando um usuário disparar uma ação (digamos internar o paciente) esta versão é confrontada com a versão que está persistida no banco. Caso haja divergência, a transação não é executada. Isto é útil para evitar por exemplo que dois usuários tentem alterar um registro ao mesmo tempo.

Imagine o seguinte: Dois usuários abrem a mesma ficha do paciente em seu sistema, ambos recebem no formulário de dados a versão do registro (digamos 1.0). O usuário A, altera a informação do paciente para "internado", o banco atualiza este valor e sobe a versão para digamos 1.1. No entanto o usuário B não sabe disso e ainda está com o formulário "antigo" em sua tela com valor da versão do registro ainda 1.0. Se ele mandar internar o mesmo paciente também, o campo da versão presente em seu formulário vai divergir do campo da versão mais recente que está no banco e a transação será cancelada. Desta forma você pode fazer o tratamento de erro adequado e informar ao usuário que aquele dado estava desatualizado.

Este mecanismo no hibernate é razoavelmente fácil de utilizar bastando apenas criar uma coluna na entidade alvo do tipo `int`, `Integer`, `long`, `Long`, `short`, `Short` ou ainda `java.sql.Timestamp` e anotar com `@Version`. O hibernate faz a gestão da versão para você.

Vou deixar aqui a referência de onde tirei um exemplo bem interessante que possa vir a te ajudar pare resolver este problema.

https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking

Espero poder te ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Como o Dherik comentou. Tendo a possibilidade de criar uma constraint acho que é a melhor opção.

algo assim:

```
ALTER TABLE pacienteInternado ADD CONSTRAINT CPFUNICO UNIQUE (cpf);
```

O erro que será retornado em caso de tentativa de cadastro duplicado:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
> Duplicate entry 'string-00000000000' for key 'pacienteInternado.CPFUNICO'

Caso a  tabela *pacienteInternado* tenha algum relacionamento com a tabela de paciente, você deve deixar o FK do paciente único. Estou especulando suas tabelas, caso seja necessário compartilhe aqui pra gente ver.